# Bootstrap dropdown click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my Bootstrap dropdown. When I click the button the menu doesn't show.

I know this question is asked many times before and I watched some tutorials on Youtube on how to make them but nothing works.

I tried many versions of Jquery and bootstrap js, I moved the scripts to the bottom of the code and I added this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

This is what I have now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <!-- link javascript -->
    <script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/dropdown.js"></script>
    
    <!-- link CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- other stuff on my page -->
  
<!-- ADMIN TOOLS --> 
    <div class="adminToolsContainer">
        <!-- dropdown -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <!-- Drowdown button -->
            <button class="btn btn-default drowdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <!-- Button title and arrow -->
                Admin tools <span class="caret"></span>
                
                <!-- Dropdown content -->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Blog</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Post lijst</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Maak post</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Accounts</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gebruikerslijst</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gebruiker toevoegen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </button>    
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END OF ADMIN TOOLS -->
</body>
```

I hope someone knows a solution. I don't know why but I always have trouble when I have to link Jquery and the bootstrap javascript.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you seeing any error when checking the Javascript Console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `.dropdown-menu` to out of the button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- link CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- other stuff on my page -->

  <!-- ADMIN TOOLS -->
  <div class="adminToolsContainer">
    <!-- dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <!-- Drowdown button -->
      <button class="btn btn-default drowdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <!-- Button title and arrow -->
        Admin tools <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- Dropdown content -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Blog</li>
        <li><a href="#">Post lijst</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maak post</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Accounts</li>
        <li><a href="#">Gebruikerslijst</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gebruiker toevoegen</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF ADMIN TOOLS -->

  <!-- link javascript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Unfortunately that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Thanks it works! What exactly have you changed? I can't find a difference.

Comment: @LordRaiders I have moved that `.dropdown-menu` to out of the `.drowdown-toggle` button.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but the problem is still current. Here's my solution:

Ensure that you include the jquery, popper.js and bootstrap scripts in the proper order. Here's what I did. I switched the order mentioned on bootstrap.com to load jQuery and popper.js first and then the bootstrap.css next

so something like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="...." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-...." crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```